# PHP range - cidr conversion

Tags: php

## I am looking for a function in PHP, which makes the same as [Perl's `Net::CIDR::range2cidr` function](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-CIDR/CIDR.pm#@cidr_list=Net::CIDR::range2cidr(@range_list);).

---

I found some solutions in Google:

- [tutorialspots - ip2cidr](http://tutorialspots.com/php-convert-ip-range-to-cidr-353.html) (Not working correctly for `['10.0.0.0', '10.255.255.255']`)
- [tutorialspots - cidr2ip](http://tutorialspots.com/php-convert-cidr-to-ipaddress-range-329.html) (Not working correctly for `"192.168.1.15/24"`)
- [flygoast/range2cidr](https://github.com/flygoast/range2cidr) (Must be installed)

---

## Is there an easier way to convert CIDR to range and back ?

(Maybe, did I just miss an existing function in PHP ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using the [s1lentium/iptools](https://packagist.org/packages/s1lentium/iptools) composer package and the following code:

```
/**
 * Perl's "Net::CIDR::range2cidr()" function.
 *
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $to
 *
 * @return array
 */
function range2cidr($from, $to) {
    $networks = IPTools\Range::parse("{$from}-{$to}")->getNetworks();

    return array_map(function(IPTools\Network $network) {
        return (string)$network;
    }, $networks);
}

/**
 * @param string $cidr
 *
 * @return array
 */
function cidr2range($cidr) {
    /** @var IPTools\Range $range */
    $range = IPTools\Network::parse($cidr)->hosts;

    return [
        (string)$range->getFirstIP(),
        (string)$range->getLastIP(),
    ];
}
```